# module matplotlib has no 'Blues' member

Tags: python-3.x

I set color 'Blues' and it can run and show the fig successfully ,but the output show a problem at here "cmap=plt.cm.Blues" and can't save the fig

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x_values = list(range(1,1001))
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]


plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c= y_values, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolor= 'none',  s=20)

#Set chart title and label axes
plt.title("Square Number" , fontsize= 15)
plt.xlabel("Value", fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel("Square of Value", fontsize = 10)

#set the range for each axis
plt.axis([0, 1100, 0, 1100000])

#set size of tick labels
plt.tick_params(axis= 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)

plt.show()
plt.savefig('squares_plot.png', bbox_inches= 'tight')
```

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `cm` is part of `matplotlib` and you only imported `matplotlib.pyplot`.
 
Try out this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
# ... your code goes here
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, c= y_values, cmap=mpl.cm.Blues, edgecolor= 'none',  s=20)
```